# Regex first color match in php

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to get the first color match by regex in php
here is my code

```
// product name (grey black)
// sample product name grey black
// product name (grey,black)
// samsung galaxy note4 golden/white/black
// $str is having one of the different product names mentioned above
$str = "product name (grey black)";
$color = ' ';
if(preg_match("#.+ ?[ \(](black|dark)#i",$str)){
    $color .= 'black';    
}else if(preg_match("#.+ ?[ \(](brown|grey)#i",$str)){
    $color .= 'grey';
}else if(preg_match("#.+ ?[ \(](golden|gold)#i",$str)){
    $color .= 'golden';
}
print $color;
```

but this code sets the black and dark as first priority, I want to get the color which is occurring at very first time in product name e.g in the string "product name (grey black)" the program should return grey at output but it returns black cause the first if condition is met with the product name having black at its second or third color.
Can anyone please help me to get an idea what logic should be implemented to get very first occurrence of color. What I know in the product names are the color names only.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Does this approach work? https://eval.in/529750 In your current approach `black` matches the first regex.

Comment: @chris85 The only problem is he wants `dark` to return `black` and not return `dark` itself.

Comment: Your code and description are contradicting. In your code you have `grey` returning `brown`; and `black` or `dark` returning `black`. In your write up you state `grey` should be returned, none of your code has `grey` ever being returned.

Comment: @chris85 thanks for pointing out! I have edited the code! Dear KayVan has provided the solution with a different logic! Got my issue solved for now!
Thanks for help, I Love http://stackoverflow.com, Thank you StackOverFlow team, Thanks KayVan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a function that goes through the string and get the first color detected.

```
function getColorFromString($string){
    $words = preg_split("/[^\w]/", $string);
    $colors = array(
        "black" => array("black", "dark"),
        "blue" => array("blue"),
        "gold" => array("gold", "golden"),
        "grey" => array("gray", "grey")
    );

    foreach($words as $word){
        foreach($colors as $key => $value){
            if(in_array(strtolower($word), $value))
                return $key;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Add the colors you need for your case. If the string contains the word `dark`, it would return `black`. Basically, the key of the array is the value to be returned, and the array itself is the alias of the key.

Example:

```
echo getColorFromString("product name (grey black)");
```

Result:

```
grey
```